# Which UI element is suitable for drop down filter in iOS app?

Tags: ios, user-interface

Right now i am developing app. One of it's ViewControllers has tableview with list of blog posts. I want to put some control so user can select blog's categories and then app will show posts only from those selected categories.

I thought it would be nice if there will be "filter" button in top right corner of my app's viewcontroller. After pressing it dropdown list of category appears and user can select categories.

What custom UI element can handle it?

Comment: You can push a modal view controller when user clicks right bar button item and use UITableView or UICollectionView according to your design to list the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for a while and can recommend **CZPicker** https://github.com/chenzeyu/CZPicker because it very nice and easy picker view for iOS that supports iOS 7 and is well working not only iPhones but whit iPads too.

Answer (score 4):

Really there's a ton of options at your disposal, not including all the custom elements you can probably grab from GitHub

For an iPad, you can use a UIPopoverController https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html

Depending on the number of filters and the style of the design, a good starting point could even be a UIActionSheet.

If you want to do something really fancy, you could have a second UITableView hidden underneath by your main UITableView containing the blog posts, and then when the "Filter" button gets hit you can animate your blog UITableView slightly over revealing your filters menu (maybe even shaded slightly darker to give a feeling of depth to the app)

Comment: You can also use popovers on an iPhone as of iOS 8. https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-drop-down-selection-behavior-in-ios-a

Comment: Yup I just realized this after reading further. It's been a while since I've worked with the popovers as I tend to like to design things differently

Comment: @GregBrown this popover is pretty what i am searching for! Thank you! Hope that i can implement it to iOS 7.

Comment: Well in iOS7 you may run into limitations with device type. In iOS8 and beyond you can actually use https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/ since UIPopoverController is deprecated as of iOS9

Comment: I believe you'll only get the actual popover UI in iOS 8 or higher. In iOS 7, I think you'll just get a full-screen modal window, but the functionality will be the same.

Comment: @ascendancy05 - Correct - the example I referenced actually uses `UIPopoverPresentationController`. So the app may need two separate code paths - one for iOS7 and another for iOS 8+.